# CSS, WordPress and IE

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer, css-float

I would like to position three items in CSS using float.

1. In the top left--logo
2. To the right of the logo, the navigation, which is an unordered list, ie floating left.
3. In the top right, a 2 line sign up for newsletter field--copy top row and form field with submit bottom in the second

I've given each it's own Div tag but can't see to get it to work with float. Only absolute positioning which doesn't look good when the site is resized. I put a table inside the div right now but would love a pure CSS solution.

I can get the logo to float left and the sign up field to float right but can't seem to get the navigation properly positioned. Either it goes all the way left or I put a clear in and it goes below the logo and field.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: you should always post your markup and css for things like this - easier for us if we have a base to start with

Comment: as well as a screenshot of what it is and what it should be, that'd help.

Answer (score 3):

What about the following?

```
    .floatleft_logo
    {
        float: left;
        width: 200px;
    }

    .floatleft_nav
    {
        float: left;
        width: 600px;
    }
    .floatright_email
    {
        float: right;
        width: 300px;
        margin-left:-250px;
    }
```

Put all three in a 850px-wide container div and this works for me in a test page.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood it correctly, maybe you could set the first and second element to float: left, and then set the margin of the third element equal to the width of the first and second?

You could also set the first element to float left, the third to float right, and the second with a margin equal to the width of the first element. Like a three-column layout.